# Button click open the another activity in class extends Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have created  ButtonFragment class , in Which we implement the
    button click method on view and identify the specific button ,When
    we click on the button event will work , but when we try to open the
    another activity like startActivity method gives error.How can we do that
    ,Can any one help me. Below is my code.

```
   package com.viewpagerex;



import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import
android.view.View; import android.view.View.OnClickListener; import
android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.ImageButton;




public class ButtonFragment extends Fragment implements  OnClickListener 
{ 

private static final String TAG = null;
    protected static final Context context=null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(TAG,"HelloHelooooo");

    }   
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   }    

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)    
     {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, container, false);    

  ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.imgButton);

        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

                return view;
}


public void onClick(View v)
 {

            if(v.getId()==R.id.imgButton) 
        {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startActivity(new Intent(ButtonFragment.this,Activity_One.class));
                Log.e(TAG,"Data show");     
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try it as :

```
startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),Activity_One.class));
```

and make sure you have declared `Activity_One` in `AndroidManifest.xml`